# Filter by one custom field, order by another?

Tags: filters, wp-query, custom-field

I have a custom post type "Listing" and I want to get all Listings that have a custom field `gateway_value != 'Yes'`, and order the results by another custom field, `location_level1_value`.  I can get the queries to work separately, but I can't combine them:

## Query 1 (sort by location):

```
                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
                    'post_type' => 'listing',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9',
                    'meta_key' => 'location_level1_value',
                    'orderby' => 'location_level1_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'paged' => $paged
                    )
                 );
```

## Query 2 (custom field value != Yes):

```
                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
                    'post_type' => 'listing',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_key' => 'gateway_value',
                    'meta_value' => 'Yes',
                    'meta_compare' => '!=',
                    'paged' => $paged
                    )
                );
```

## Combined query:

I looked at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) for help with this, but the following query does not work:

```
                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
                    'post_type' => 'listing',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'gateway_value',
                            'value' => 'Yes',
                            'compare' => '!='
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'location_level1_value'
                        )
                    ),
                    'orderby' => "location_level1_value",
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'paged' => $paged
                    )
                );
```

What am I doing wrong with the combined query?

[UPDATE]: So now that 3.1 has been released, the combined query above still does not work. I do get results, just not sorted correctly.

[UPDATE]: `var_dump($wp_query->request)` gives the following:
`string(527) " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_7v1oev_posts.* FROM wp_7v1oev_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_7v1oev_postmeta ON (wp_7v1oev_posts.ID = wp_7v1oev_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_7v1oev_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_7v1oev_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_7v1oev_posts.post_type = 'listing' AND (wp_7v1oev_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND wp_7v1oev_postmeta.meta_key = 'gateway_value' AND CAST(wp_7v1oev_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != 'Yes' AND mt1.meta_key = 'location_level1_value'  ORDER BY wp_7v1oev_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 9"`

Comment: Are you using WordPress 3.1? The `meta_query` parameter is new in 3.1, due to be released very soon, but the current stable version is still 3.0.5, without this parameter.

Comment: Er... right, that would probably be why then. Any way to get it to work in 3.0.5?

Comment: Miljenko has the best answer you should accept his instead of yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the query to filter the content as you intended by using the 'meta_query' with filtering options, and for the order part, just add/modify the following parameters:

- 'orderby' => 'meta_value'
- 'meta_key' => 'location_level1_value'
- 'order' => 'ASC'

  ```
  $wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
      'post_type'      => 'listing',
      'posts_per_page' => '9',
      'post_status'    => 'publish',
      'meta_query'     => array(
          array(
              'key'       => 'gateway_value',
              'value'     => 'Yes',
              'compare'   => '!='
          )
      ),
      'orderby'  => 'meta_value',            // this means we will be using a selected 
                                             // meta field to order

      'meta_key' => 'location_level1_value', // this states which meta field 
                                             // will be used in the ordering, 
                                             // regardless of the filters
      'order'    => 'ASC',
      'paged'    => $paged
      )
  );
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Just like Jan said in new WordPress 3.1 you can use `meta_query` but until that will come out you can use your First query to orderby and filter inside your loop like so:

```
 Global $my_query;
$my_query = new WP_Query( array (
                    'post_type' => 'listing',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9',
                    'meta_key' => 'location_level1_value',
                    'orderby' => 'location_level1_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'paged' => $paged
                    )
                 );
while ($my_query->have_posts){
    $my_query->the_post();
              //do your loop stuff
}
```

and add this code to your functions.php

```
   //join filter
         add_filter('posts_join', 'listing_join_865' );
         function listing_join_865($join){
Global$ my_query;            
if ('listing' = $my_query->query['post_type']){
                $restriction1 = 'gateway_value';
                return $join .="
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS $restriction1 ON(
                $wpdb->posts.ID = $restriction1.post_id
                AND $restriction1.meta_key = '$restriction1'
                )";
             }else {
                return $join;
            }
         }
         //where filter
         add_filter('posts_where', 'listing_where_865' );
         function listing_where_865($where){
             global $my_query;
            if ('listing' = $my_query->query['post_type']){
                return $where.= " AND $restriction1.meta_value != 'yes'";
            }else{
                return $where;
            }
         }
```

now this should work.

Comment: Thanks for this. This works, except I have this odd side effect that my paging doesn't work properly any more. Instead of 9 per page, I have "blank spots" in my grid where the custom posts that have `gateway_value == "Yes"` would have been without the conditional... Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: yea that would mess up the paging so i guess the only way around it would be a custom sql query, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Don't worry - I will just use the second query and use the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order until 3.1 is released :)

Comment: dam, i got back just now to see your comment after finding a solution. anyway it's here for future askers.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - If you tab in all your code it will be easier to paste into answers. **Eg.** Put it in your chosen editor, select it all, then tab it in once, now copy and paste, and you'll avoid needing to add 4 spaces before any lines of the code(it should all go into a code block nicely without any need to fiddle around).

Comment: @t31os - i usually do that but not when answering from my cell phone.

Comment: You wrote that from a phone... respect!.. i'd not even try writing code on a phone.. :) +1 for the phone skillz! ;)

Comment: t31os: LOL , HTC desire rocks!!

Comment: I've tried pasting in blocks of tabbed code from my text editor and it never works - I always have to add the spaces

Comment: Copy paste from notepad++ in firefox works fine.

Comment: I'll try that (currently using PsPad and Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for answering my own question:

Looking at [http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15031][1], seems like this is a known issue. I have fixed (hacked?) it to work using `post_filter`, like so (just for anyone's reference who might be searching for the same answer):

#### In functions.php###

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'EV_locationl1' );
function EV_locationl1 ($orderby) {
    global $EV_locationl1_orderby;
    if ($EV_locationl1_orderby) $orderby = $EV_locationl1_orderby;
    return $orderby;
}
```

#### Amended wp_query in template file###

```
$EV_locationl1_orderby = " mt1.meta_value ASC";

$wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'posts_per_page' => '9',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                    'key' => 'gateway_value',
                    'value' => 'Yes',
                    'compare' => '!='
                    ),
            array(
                    'key' => 'location_level1_value'
            )
        ),
    'order' => $EV_locationl1_orderby,
    'paged' => $paged
    ));
```